# Android - Drawer Layout - Close drawers causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

I am having trouble closing a Drawer Layout in Android. Every time I call drawer.closeDrawers() or drawer.closeDrawers(list) I run into a Null Pointer Exception.

Here is my MainActivity.java code.

```
// Sliding drawer menu
private DrawerLayout drawer;
// Drawer list
private ListView drawerList;
...
...
...
// List of menu options
final String[] menu = new String[]{
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4",
        "Item 5"
};
// Initialize the drawer menu layout
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
// Initialize the drawer list
drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
// Drawer list adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu);
// Set the adapter for the list
drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
// Set the background selector for each menu item
drawerList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
// On click listener for the list
drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    // When a menu item is clicked
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> e, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Close the drawer
        drawer.closeDrawers(); // Causes a Null Pointer Exception
    }
});
```

Here is my activity_main.xml code.

```
<!-- Left sided swipe in Drawer layout -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Google maps fragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </fragment>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my error stack trace.

```
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): Process: com.dziz.umbcparkingpal, PID: 1959
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.dziz.umbcparkingpal.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:108)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-30 20:29:21.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing to cause this Null Pointer Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Drawer with,

```
drawer= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate the layout before retrieving the views from within it:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

then you can fetch the views:

```
drawerList = (ListView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
```

Comment: This did not work. Android ran into an error with trying to inflate the view. Also, you weren't very specific with what I'm supposed to do with the inflated view, it just hangs there unused.

Comment: the "view" is your "drawer"

Comment: Yeah I tried initializing my DrawerLayout with the inflated view using a cast. It didn't help, it only crashed the program on start.

Comment: That sounds really weird. There might be several issues with your code. However, this was one of them.

Comment: It has to do something with my google maps fragment, I need this fragment in there however. Is there any other way to get rid of my null pointer exception without inflating the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by calling this:

```
 DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

within the fragment. Where MainActivity is the activity where you put your drawer_layout.

Also make sure that you get the reference to the drawerLayout right before you call  closeDrawers() because in my case I still got a NullPointer when calling the findViewById() at the start of onCreateView() of my fragment.

So in your case call the findViewById() from within your onItemClicked() method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have use drawer and it's run perfectly with out any error. This is some portion of my code . I think it might help you.

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.d("Activity :", getClass().getName().toString());

            initDrawer(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void initDrawer(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.student_nav_drawer_items);
            navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
                    R.array.student_nav_drawer_icons);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();


            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

            adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_titlebar);

            tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            tvTitle.setText(getString(R.string.title_activity_home));

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.slider_icon, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name

            ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                selectItem(0);

            }
        }

private void selectItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            break;

        case 3:


            break;
        default:


            break;
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#444"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mRecyclerDrawer)){
>                               mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(listview);
>                           }else {
>                               mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(listview);
>                           }